# Trouble with Glass.Mapper InferType property

Tags: glass-mapper

I am trying to use Glass.Mapper's InferType property. I've read through the tutorial on the Glass [website](http://www.glass.lu/mapper/sc/tutorials/tutorial17). I have two alert types that have different markup. They both inherit from the same base class AssetAlert that contains a property that holds the alert message. This code does not work as it is and when I debug it, the type returned is of the base class instead of the appropriate derived class. I have already updated GlassMapperScCustom.cs like the tutorial says.

How can I confirm that Glass has loaded all of the models from my assembly properly?

And if that's not the issue, can anyone see anything wrong with my code that might be preventing it from inferring the correct derived class instead of the base class?

I'm using Glass.Mapper 4.3.4.196 and Sitecore 8.2 rev. 161115

I have these classes:

`FundDetail.cs`

```
// ReSharper disable once ClassWithVirtualMembersNeverInherited.Global
[SitecoreType(AutoMap = true, TemplateId = "{1813C6E1-72AD-41B9-9D68-372A843BCCCB}")]
public class FundDetail : StandardItem
{
    [SitecoreQuery("./Alerts/*", IsRelative = true, InferType = true)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<AssetAlert> AssetAlerts { get; [UsedImplicitly] set; }
}
```

`AssetAlert.cs`

```
// ReSharper disable once ClassWithVirtualMembersNeverInherited.Global
[SitecoreType(AutoMap = true, TemplateId = "{607D5F70-D3A5-4690-A2EC-259A4700D2E3}")]
public class AssetAlert : StandardItem
{
    [SitecoreField("{0797970F-D9E6-4FB2-86EA-CF271CCA0629}")]
    public virtual string Message { get; [UsedImplicitly] set; }
}
```

`AssetUpdateAlert.cs`

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{9DAE0D23-6524-4D31-B23E-B4D16E1ADDE0}")]
public class AssetUpdateAlert : AssetAlert
{
    private const string DictionaryFolder = "/Content Types/Asset Alert/";
    public static string Title
        => DictionaryPhraseRepository.Current.Get(DictionaryFolder + "Update Title");
}
```

`AssetShareholderInformationAlert.cs`

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{2B5FB48B-4ED8-4B3A-8D29-AFDF5A3D66FB}")]
public class AssetShareholderInformationAlert : AssetAlert
{
    private const string DictionaryFolder = "/Content Types/Asset Alert/";
    public static string Title
        => DictionaryPhraseRepository.Current.Get(DictionaryFolder + "Shareholder Information Title");
}
```

`FundDetail.cshtml` (I removed the markup for readability)

```
@if (Model.AssetAlerts != null)
{
    foreach (var alert in Model.AssetAlerts)
    {
        @if (alert is AssetUpdateAlert)
        {
            @AssetUpdateAlert.Title
            @Editable(alert, a => a.Message)
        }
        else if (alert is AssetShareholderInformationAlert)
        {
            @AssetShareholderInformationAlert.Title
            @Editable(alert, a => a.Message)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does putting the AutoMap = true to derived types resolve your issue?

Comment: I added AutoMap = true per your suggestion, but am getting the same results as before. When I debug the application, I can see that the item is still of type AssetAlert.cs.

Comment: Does this kind of cast work for you with automap? `alert as AssetUpdateAlert`

Comment: Hmm, no it does not. I added "var testalert = alert as AssetUpdateAlert;" to my view inside of the foreach loop and in the debugger testalert is null. I assume that means it was not able to cast alert to AssetUpdateAlert?

Comment: check if there are actually items of needed templates and also that they are published

Comment: I have two items in the Alerts folder in Sitecore. One alert for each template type. The template GUIDs match the ones used in the models. Everything is published as well. Is there anything else on the Sitecore side of things I need to make sure of? Currently I have the AssetUpdateAlert and AssetShareholderInformationAlert templates using AssetAlert as their base template. Is this correct?

Comment: Also, when I am in the debugger, Model.AssertAlerts correcly lists the two items from Sitecore. They are just of type AssertAlert instead of their respective types.

Comment: does that answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20970534/2183396

Comment: No, I've already done that

Comment: Do you know how I can verify that the models from the assembly have been loaded into Glass properly?

Comment: I am not sure. I guess you need to find its mapping collection somewhere

Comment: I found that you can check the TypeConfiguration property on the context item in GlassMapperSc.cs. In there I could see that my models are all being loaded properly, so that is not the issue. I am not sure what to try next but will keep researching. Thank you for your help. If you have any other ideas, please let me know!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem before. After adding the below lines to GlassMapperScCustom class, the InferType attribute works.

```
public static IConfigurationLoader[] GlassLoaders()
{
    var attributes = new AttributeConfigurationLoader("your assembly name where the models locate");

    return new IConfigurationLoader[] { attributes };
}
```